# Using GetStringWidth in TCPDF to short a string

Tags: php, while-loop, tcpdf, substr

I'm using TCPDF to print a Barcode sheet label.
Each label has a barcode and some text underneath.
Evreything seems to work fine, but somtimes the text is to long and 'invade' the next label/next line.

I'm trying to check the length of the string - and short it if needed:

```
$label_w = ($page_w-$right_mar-$left_mar)/$Col;
$text_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($exploded_line[2]);
while ($text_width>$label_w-15) // "-15" because the text location
    {
        $exploded_line[2]=substr($exploded_line[2],0,-1);
        $text_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($exploded_line[2]);
    }
```

The text that going into the loop just continue shrinking until **only the first letter left**...

At first I thought that the problem is that my `While` condition isn't stopping for some reason. 
Then I tried changing it to simple `if` - BUT the problem isn't gone...

```
if ($text_width>$label_w-15)
    {
        $exploded_line[2]=substr($exploded_line[2],0,-1);
        $text_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($exploded_line[2]);
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `$label_w` and `$text_width` to ensure they're good? The logic looks fine, and is basically the same thing I do, but I shrink font size instead of cutting characters off.

Comment: Sure, `$label_w` is 70 in the example, and `$text_width` is between 40-62... if it's more than 55 (=70-15) the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I got it.
The problem was really in the `substr` function. I'm using UTF-8, so I had to use `mb_substr`...

```
$exploded_line[2]=mb_substr($exploded_line[2],0,-1,"utf-8");
```

This is working as expected.
Thanks anyway.